# Name this animated film/movie - boy chases a glowing orb

Tags: story-identification

For lots of years I've had a film in my head that for the life of me can not remember what it's called. It was animated and starts with some sort of bird over a cliff/mountain. It included a boy that finds some sort of orb-looking thing, like a bright green light. In the film it jumps and the steps light up so the boy chases after it. It ends where the boy helps this green thing find his family, as he lost them when the spaceship came crashing down. Any ideas? It's been driving me insane for years.

Comment: Heavy Metal? It has spaceships and a green orb. The green orb normally doesn't help people though.

Comment: @cde - Aside from the glowing orb, that doesn't fit the description at all.

Comment: @Richard glowing orb, animated, spaceships crashing, old, etc. Its more than just the loc-narr, and also why i said it in a comment

Comment: @cde - No, it's **MY** loc-narr!